# Tables within tables in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

Ok, well, I have to define the following table:

[image]

I've been working for at least 30 minutes but I can't figure it how to make it. I need some explanation how does tables within tables work and how would I create the table above.

```
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="800px" height="600px">
    <tr>
        <td height=120px>

        </td>
        <td width=280px>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td height=300px>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *I've been working for at least 30 minutes* can we see your work?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Sure, but I haven't managed to get it started. I always end up with some trouble and can't continue..

Comment: Please take the downvote back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need multiple tables

Use  rowspan and colspan properties of table cells

To understand where to use rowspan and colspan, take your picture and continue all the lines dividing table cell to cross entire table. You will see what will need to be joined vertically with rowspan or horizontally with colspan.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan=2 width=500 height=120></td>
    <td rowspan=2 width=270 height=300></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=2 width=120></td>
    <td rowspan=2 width=400></td>       
</tr>
<tr>            
    <td height=300></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you still need tables, I would create 3 tables here- top right and left-bottom

```
    <table heigth=600 width=800 border=1>
    <tr>
        <td height=120 width=520>1</td>
        <td rowspan=2 width=270 height=600 valign=top>
            <table valign=top border=1 width=270>
                <tr><td height=300>2</td></tr>
                <tr><td height=300>3</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign=top>
            <table width=520 border=1 height=480>
                <tr>
                    <td width=120>4</td>
                    <td width=400>5</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You should provide a solution, or consider posting this as a comment :)

Comment: @vittore Actually, I do need in this case, because the exercise specifies to use tables within tables..

Comment: @Mr.Alien it is totally possible

Comment: @Mr.Alien because last row has empty cell and no size specified. Add height to it.

Comment: @vittore sorry would like to take my comment back, I actually had added height previously but thought that OP has height restrictions too, so I ruled out the rowspan colspan possibility :) so +1

Comment: @vittore Can you explain why do we have 3 rows?

Comment: That is minimum number of rows to render such a layout. just continue all lines on your picture to cross table up-down and left-right to the border of the table. You will see what kind of layout you need and what have to be joined using rowspan/colspan

Comment: @vittore Thanks. The example with table within tables doesn't display very good for some reason

Comment: @user2943407 That's because i gave you only structure. Added more formating anyway.